# How to pass local text file to ssh command?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh, solaris

I am writing a script in Unix that needs to:

1. Create a local text file
2. Log in via ssh (e.g. user@servername)
3. Do stuff with local text file
4. End script

Unfortunately, I can't do this because once the script logs in via ssh, it can't see the text file.  So I am trying to pass a local text to the ssh command, so it will see the text file.

Text file is resembles this

```
user@servername1
user@servername2
user@servername3
... etc
```

I looked on a previous answer from SuperUser, but their solution just returns errors for me.

```
ssh user@servername < text.txt
#stty: : Invalid argument
#sh: user@servername1: not found
#sh[2]: user@servername2: not found
#sh[3]: user@servername3: not found
#...etc
```

Comment: You can have a look [there](http://superuser.com/questions/48783/how-can-i-pass-an-environment-variable-through-an-ssh-command), but apart from passing an environment variable to ssh (which is certainly inconvenient but can be done through a here-document in Bash, even if the file is big), you have to accept there is no way except sending the file to the remote host, as suggested by glenn below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

1. create a local text file
2. transfer the file to the remote host: `scp local_file user@servername:./remote_file`
3. login to the remote host and do stuff: `ssh user@servername cat -n remote_file`

Answer (score 0):

if you need to work with local file, not with remote copy, you can try to do next: call `ssh` command in a different terminal, then you can continue to work locally and process you local file

`xterm -e "bash -c \"ssh user@servername; exec bash\"" &`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @glennjackman's two connections to copy and then execute...

Since you can [pipe commands to ssh](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=pipe+to+ssh), which is quite similar to your example,

```
echo "ls" | ssh localhost
```

All you need is something in the middle to interpret the text file. For example...

```
cat text.txt | sed 's/^/finger /' | ssh user@servername
#or
cat text.txt | ssh user@servername xargs finger
```

---

In your example, `ssh user@servername` and `user@servername1` are pretty similar. Just to be clear you didn't want to use those in the ssh command itself?:

```
while read user
do
ssh $user echo hi #ssh to each user/server in turn
done <text.txt
```